# Twisted pipe two processes with spawnProcess

Tags: python, process, pipe, twisted

I'm trying to use Twisted with Python2.7 for piping two processes.

What I'd like to do is:

```
myImagesPipesGenerator | ffmpeg -i -
```

myImagesPipesGenerator is outputing on stdout an infinite list of BMP images.
FFmpeg is getting those pictures on stdin and encoding them in a video

So I need to:

```
generatorTransport = reactor.spawnProcess(myInputProtocol, "myImagesPipesGenerator", ["myImagesPipesGenerator",], env=None, childFDs={0:'w', 1:'r', 2:'r'})
ffmpegTransport = reactor.spawnProcess(myOutputProtocol, "ffmpeg", ["ffmpeg","-i","-"], env=None, childFDs={0:__What_to_use_here__, 1:'r', 2:'r'})
```

How to get the "output" file descriptor of generatorTransport stdout pipe, so I can use it in childFDs for ffmpegTransport?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the pipe yourself:

```
read, write = os.pipe()
```

And then pass the file descriptors where you want the children to use them.  Something like:

```
generatorTransport = reactor.spawnProcess(..., childFDs={1: write})
ffmpegTransport = reactor.spawnProcess(..., childFDs={0: read})
```

Comment: I could not get your approach to work. Instead I chained the process protocols and that seems to work much better. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513516/twisted-spawnprocess-send-output-of-one-process-to-input-of-another/27514646#27514646