# Twisted spawnProcess, send output of one process to input of another

Tags: python, process, twisted

I am trying to use twisted spawnProcess to replicate the behavior of something like this:

```
cat <input.txt | wc -w
```

This is just an example of two commands, in reality I have my own processes (say python or bash scripts or external programs) where each process reads from stdin and writes to stdout. Just like the above example, I want to pipe stdout from one process to stdin of another, and I want to do this using spawnProcess. I used some hints here:

[Twisted pipe two processes with spawnProcess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012265/twisted-pipe-two-processes-with-spawnprocess)

but I can't get it to work. It just hangs when reading from stdin on the second spawnProcess protocol. My code is below.What am I doing wrong? How exactly can I achieve this objective? Is it better to call the second spawnProcess from within the first?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
import re
import os
import sys

class CatPP(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
    def __init__(self,input_data):
        self.input_data=input_data
        self.data = ""

    def connectionMade(self):
        print "connectionMade in CatPP! Now writing to stdin of cat"
        print "   writing this data: %s" % self.input_data
        self.transport.write(self.input_data+'\n')
        print "   closing stdin"
        self.transport.closeStdin() # tell them we're done
        print "   stdin closed"

    def outReceived(self, data):
        print "outReceived from cat! with %d bytes!" % len(data)
        self.data = self.data + data
        print "    received this: %s" % self.data

    def errReceived(self, data):
        print "errReceived from cat! with %d bytes!" % len(data)

    def inConnectionLost(self):
        print "inConnectionLost for cat! stdin is closed! (we probably did it)"

    def outConnectionLost(self):
        print "outConnectionLost for cat! The child closed their stdout!"
        # now is the time to examine what they wrote
        print "I saw cat write this:", self.data

    def errConnectionLost(self):
        print "errConnectionLost for cat! The child closed their stderr."

    def processExited(self, reason):
        print "processExited for cat, status %d" % (reason.value.exitCode,)

    def processEnded(self, reason):
        print "processEnded for cat, status %d" % (reason.value.exitCode,)

class WcPP(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = ""

    def connectionMade(self):
        print "connectionMade! Now reading from pipe to get stdin for wp"
        print "    reading from stdin"
        txt = sys.stdin.read()
        print "  Read this from stdin: %s" % (txt,)
        self.transport.write(txt)
        self.transport.closeStdin() # tell them we're done

    def outReceived(self, data):
        print "outReceived from cat! with %d bytes!" % len(data)
        self.data = self.data + data

    def errReceived(self, data):
        print "errReceived from cat! with %d bytes!" % len(data)

    def inConnectionLost(self):
        print "inConnectionLost for cat! stdin is closed! (we probably did it)"

    def outConnectionLost(self):
        print "outConnectionLost for cat! The child closed their stdout!"
        # now is the time to examine what they wrote
        print "Final output:", self.data
        #(dummy, lines, words, chars, file) = re.split(r'\s+', self.data)
        #print "I saw %s lines" % lines

    def errConnectionLost(self):
        print "errConnectionLost for cat! The child closed their stderr."

    def processExited(self, reason):
        print "processExited for cat, status %d" % (reason.value.exitCode,)

    def processEnded(self, reason):
        print "processEnded for cat, status %d" % (reason.value.exitCode,)
        reactor.stop()

readPipe, writePipe = os.pipe()

handle=open('junkin.txt','r')
cat_txt=handle.read()
handle.close()

pp1 = CatPP(cat_txt)
pp2 = WcPP()
reactor.spawnProcess(pp1, "cat", ["cat"], {}, childFDs={1: writePipe})
reactor.spawnProcess(pp2, "wc", ["wc", "-w"], {},childFDs={0: readPipe})
reactor.run()
try:
    os.close(readPipe)
except:
    print "Exception closing readPipe"
try:
    os.close(writePipe)
except:
    print "Exception closing writePipe"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example.

In the case of piping through `cat | wc`, `spawnProcess` duplicates the pipes so you need to close them.

```
from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
import os

class Writer(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
  def connectionMade(self):
    print "Writer -- connection made"
    self.transport.writeToChild(0, self.data)
    self.transport.closeChildFD(0)
  def childDataReceived(self, fd, data):
    pass
  def processEnded(self, status):
    pass

class Reader(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def connectionMade(self):
    print "Reader -- connection made"
    pass
  def childDataReceived(self, fd, data):
    print "Reader -- childDataReceived"
    self.received = data
  def processEnded(self, status):
    print "process ended, got:", self.received

class WriteRead(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
  def connectionMade(self):
    self.transport.writeToChild(0, self.data)
    self.transport.closeChildFD(0)
  def childDataReceived(self, fd, data):
    self.received = data
    print "got data:", data
  def processEnded(self, status):
    print "process ended - now what?"

def test1(data):
    # just call wc
    p2 = reactor.spawnProcess(WriteRead(data), "wc", ["wc"], env=None, childFDs={0: "w", 1: "r"})
    reactor.run()

def test2(data):
    rfd, wfd = os.pipe()
    p1 = reactor.spawnProcess(Writer(data), "cat", ["cat"], env=None, childFDs={0:"w", 1: wfd })
    p2 = reactor.spawnProcess(Reader(),     "wc", ["wc", "-w"], env=None, childFDs={0: rfd, 1: "r"})
    os.close(rfd)
    os.close(wfd)
    reactor.run()

test2("this is a test")
```

Comment: This looks pretty good - maybe worth noting that the primary fix here is to supply `wc` with a stdout.  That seems like the main difference from the code in the question (without giving wc stdout, it has nowhere to send its results, so you'll never see anything happen).

Comment: If you found it useful how about at least an up vote?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out how to do it but without using the pipes approach from [Twisted pipe two processes with spawnProcess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012265/twisted-pipe-two-processes-with-spawnprocess), which I never got to work. Instead I used a class ChainableProcessProtocol that takes another ChainableProcessProtocol as an argument.This way you can chain these together, with the output of a prior protocol writing to the stdin of the next protocol. This chaining stops when the next_protocol is None. The final output is the data from the final protocol. Here is my example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
import re
import os
import sys
import json

def shutdown(x):
    print "Shutdown called"
    reactor.stop()

class ChainableProcessProtocol(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
    def __init__(self,cmd,cmdargs,input_data,next_protocol):
        self.cmd=cmd
        self.cmdargs=cmdargs
        self.input_data=input_data
        self.next_protocol=next_protocol
        self.data = ""

    def set_input_data(self,new_input_data):
        self.input_data=new_input_data

    def connectionMade(self):
        print "connectionMade in %s! Now writing to stdin of cat" % self.cmd
        print "   writing this data: %s" % self.input_data
        self.transport.write(self.input_data+'\n')
        print "   closing stdin"
        self.transport.closeStdin() # tell them we're done
        print "   stdin closed"

    def outReceived(self, data):
        print "outReceived from %s! with %d bytes!" % (self.cmd,len(data))
        self.data = self.data + data
        print "    received this: %s" % self.data

    def errReceived(self, data):
        print "errReceived from %s! with %d bytes!" % (self.cmd,len(data))

    def inConnectionLost(self):
        print "inConnectionLost for %s! stdin is closed! (we probably did it)" %(self.cmd,)

    def outConnectionLost(self):
        print "outConnectionLost for %s! The child closed their stdout!" %(self.cmd,)
        # now is the time to examine what they wrote
        print "I saw %s write this: %s" % (self.cmd,self.data)
        #
        # cmd is done, now write to next_protocol if set
        #
        if self.next_protocol:
            print "Calling chained protocol"
            self.next_protocol.set_input_data(self.data)
            npcmd=self.next_protocol.cmd
            npcmdargs=self.next_protocol.cmdargs
            print "npcmd is %s" % (npcmd,)
            print "npcmdargs is %s" % (json.dumps(npcmdargs),)
            reactor.spawnProcess(self.next_protocol, npcmd, npcmdargs, {})
        else:
            print "No chained protocol"

    def errConnectionLost(self):
        print "errConnectionLost for %s! The child closed their stderr." % (self.cmd,)

    def processExited(self, reason):
        print "processExited for %s, status %d" % (self.cmd,reason.value.exitCode,)

    def processEnded(self, reason):
        print "processEnded for %s, status %d" % (self.cmd,reason.value.exitCode,)

handle=open('junkin.txt','r')
in_txt=handle.read()
handle.close()

#
# Create the last protocol first because earlier protocol(s) need it
#
pp2 = ChainableProcessProtocol("wc",["wc","-w"],'',None)
#
# The first process takes an instance of the second process as an argument
#
pp1 = ChainableProcessProtocol("cat",["cat"],in_txt,pp2)
#
# before using spawnProcess, lets create a deferred to shut down the reactor in 2 seconds
# This should give us enough time. This is only so our test script does not run forever
#
d=defer.Deferred()
d.addCallback(shutdown)
reactor.callLater(2, d.callback, '')
#
# Now spawn the first process
#
reactor.spawnProcess(pp1, pp1.cmd, pp1.cmdargs, {})
reactor.run()
print "Final output is data in pp2: %s" % (pp2.data.strip(),)
print "Done!"
```

Comment: Thanks. Both answers do indeed work. My chaining approach is a little more complex but does not require explicit pipes. Your approach is simpler but it requires that you explicitly open and remember to close the pipes. Closing properly is very important in persistent/embedded applications. Anyway, it's great to see that there are two good solutions to this.